# Why is my Django image not uploading in media/eventimg folder?

Tags: django, django-models

python

```
class Events(models.Model):
    user_name = models.TextField()
    e_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='eventimg')
    e_poster = models.ImageField(upload_to='eventimg')
    e_end_date = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.e_name

    def create_event(self, value): #value is send from view.py, below is its structure
        self.user_name = value['username']
        self.e_image = value['image']
        self.e_poster = value['poster']
        self.e_start_date = value['startdate']
```

```
value dictionary structure which is been send as parameter
 value= {
            'username': request.POST.get('userName'),
            'image': request.POST.get('eventImage'),
            'poster': request.POST.get('poster'),
            'enddate': datetime.strptime(request.POST.get('endDate'), '%d-%m-%Y').strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
                   }
```

Image is not uploading in media/eventimg folder. When i upload it from admin panel it is working but when i try to do same from my webpage its not working.

Comment: It might help if you showed the html.  Are you using a form with `enctype='multipart/form-data'`?

Comment: actually i am directly importing data from POST method in view.py then sending it in my models.py. MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'